# configuring jquery autocomplete with foundation

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, autocomplete, zurb-foundation

I configured jquery autocomplete with the [rails4-autocomplete](https://github.com/peterwillcn/rails4-autocomplete#installing) gem

**Controller**

```
class SuggestionsController < ApplicationController
  autocomplete :school, :name
end
```

**Routes**

```
resources :suggestions do
  get :autocomplete_school_name, :on => :collection
end
```

**View**

```
<div>
  <%= f.label :school %>
  <%= f.autocomplete_field :school, autocomplete_school_name_suggestions_path %>
</div>
```

The problem is, is that the the view is rendering the autocomplete incorrectly with foundation. Currently, as shown below, the autocomplete suggestions is begin recommending below the label, and above the autocomplete field.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're missing the jQueryUI CSS, so be sure you have this in your application.css:

`*= require jquery.ui.autocomplete`